# Add element to Hub header

Tags: windows, xaml, microsoft-metro

the hub design is builded in MSN's app, like sport, new, weather.

I want to use that, too.

I study textbook and found that tutorial.

but that only teach add header to hub

```
<Hub Header="this header"> </Hub>
```

not include element

in msn app, it has search icon in header.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hub class has a content presenter in itself and can present HubSection which you can find detailed MSDN page by [clicking here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hubsection)

I don't know which MSN app you are mentioning , but if you want to search icon in your Headers you must modify HeaderTemplate to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Hub Header="Text Your Header">
    <Hub.HeaderTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <!-- Put you element here -->
              <!-- Below is example -->
              <ListBox>
                   <ListBoxItem>No.1 </ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>No.2 </ListBoxItem>
              </ListBox>
         </DataTemplate>
    </Hub.HeaderTemplate>
</Hub>
```

Comment: Be sure to add text to your answer.

Comment: mmm...what's mean? I just start use stackoverflow for few weeks

Comment: It is a pretty old question which seems to be marked as answered. You should only add answers if you really add to the content.

Comment: so...I should delete this reply and paste the code to my top question content. that's you mean?